# Flexible llighting method in 2D (using OpenGL)

Tags: opengl, 2d, rendering, game-engine

I'm working on a simple 2D game engine. I'd like to support a variety of light types, like the [URP in Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.1/manual/Lights-2D-intro.html). Lighting would be calculated according to the normal and specular maps attached to the sprite.

Because of the different geometry of the light types, it would be ideal to defer the lighting calculations, and use a dedicated shader for it. However it would limit the user in the folowing ways:

- No transparent textures, as they would override the normal and specular data, so the sprites behind would appear unlit.
- No stylized lighting (like a toon shader) for individual sprites.

To resolve these issues I tried implementing something like in Godot. In a Godot shader, one can write a light function, that is called per pixel for every light in range. Now I have two shaders per sprite. One that outputs normal and specular information to an intermediate framebuffer, and a light shader that is called on the geometry of the light, and outputs to the screen.

The problem is that this method decreeses performance significantly, because I change buffers and shaders twice for every sprite, and the draw calls per frame also doubled.

Is there a way to decrease this methods overhead?
Or is there any other solution to this problem, that i missed?

Comment: It sounds like Godot is doing a forward (i.e. normal i.e. usual) renderer *without* intermediate buffer. What is the point of writing an intermediate buffer and then reading it again for the same sprite? May as well do all the calculations in the same shader.

Comment: Godot only supports a sprite light, but i also want to support other types, wich have different attributes (like the freeform, wich has unique geometry). Because of this, i cant sent all the lighting information into the sprites shader.

Comment: Can't you? What if you built a sprite-light sprite shader and also a freeform-light sprite shader and so on?

Comment: I may misunderstood what you wrote, but that would imply that only one light can illuminate a sprite.

Comment: maybe render a whole bunch of sprites and then light them all at once.

Comment: Maybe you reverse it - maybe you render all the lights into an intermediate buffer and then shade the sprites using the light buffer?

Comment: Lighting sprites together would only work for special cases when they use the same shader and they does not overlap if the texture is transparent. Also I'd like to batch such sprites together into one geometry in the future, so they can be rendered in one draw call. So it would only fix the problem temporarily.

Comment: A lightmap would not work because for the normal calculation I also need the direction of the light. When two lights illuminate a pixel from opposing directions, the would cancel out.

Comment: The lightmap could work afterall, if I bake the lights in view into different textures. The rgb channels could represent the direction multiplied by intensity (the texture format would be non clamped float of course). Then the shaders can recieve the baked textures.

Comment: I saw an idea somewhere to bake lighting by storing how the object reacts to light in different directions. For 3 directions they used left, up-right, down-right. But if you also use the alpha channel it could be up,down,left,right. You would think lights from other directions would look bad, but when they did it, it looked okay.

Comment: Do all your sprites really all use different shaders and transparent textures? Or do they mostly use the same shader?

Comment: "I may misunderstood what you wrote, but that would imply that only one light can illuminate a sprite." - if your lighting is additive, you can render the sprite multiple times with additive blending. If you choose to go with that idea.